# How to specify company in resume when selling products as a freelancer on a website

Tags: resume

I have been creating and uploading/selling courses on Udemy as a full-time job, for a shorter period (<2 years).

In my resume, is it acceptable to use the following title and company: Freelance "Subject" instructor - Udemy.

I am afraid that people will believe I was employed directly by Udemy and when I explain the situation, they will get the impression I'm hiding something.

At the same time, I would like to keep Udemy in there as it is a known brand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this sounds like you were contracted as a freelancer by Udemy directly, when what you actually did was using Udemy as a marketplace for selling your content.

A better phrasing could be:

> Self-employed content creator of instructional videos about [topic] on Udemy

You might want to use the text of your cover letter to brag about the reception of your videos (how many views they got, how well they were rated, etc.). You could also drop a link to your Udemy profile page so they can see your work for themselves.